# Read Excel file and write the data to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, xlrd

I have a Excel file with two columns like the following:

```
Reviews| Numbers
text1 | 1,3
text2 | 2
text3 | 1
text4 | 2
text5 | 1
```

I am reading the data as follows:

```
def read_xls(filename):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    data=[]
    for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
        reviews, numbers = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=2)
        data.append(reviews)
```

But instead of getting the columns as  separate lists, I want the result in a dictionary as follows:

```
{1: [text1, text3, text5], 2: [text2, text4], 3: [text1]}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library to read the file as a `Dataframe` and use the [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method.

Comment: @vmg that won't work since the keys will be the column headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the code below

```
def read_xls(filename):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    data = {}
    for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
        reviews, numbers = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=2)
        number_list = numbers.split(",")
        for number in number_list: 
            if number not in data:
                data[number] = []
            data[number].append(reviews)
```

Comment: I tried your method, but the issue I'm facing is that in the numbers column, there could be more than one numbers as well. So for that the review needs to go in both numbers. I just updated my question, sorry.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have supposed the numbers parameter was a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): 
    reviews, numbers = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=2)
    data[numbers].append(reviews)
```